# Making reccurence relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have trouble in understanding how to make recurrence relations. I read some of the questions on stack exchange but this stuff is not intuitive to me.
For example, when we want to find a number of ternary string that don't contain 00 sequence  the solution is a $a_n=2b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}$. To not have two consecutive zeros our last number should be 1 or 2 and our two last numbers should be any number except the one that ends in 0. Somehow we arrive at the recurrence relation mentioned earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we know $b_{n-1}$ and $b_{n-2}$, consider a ternary string of length $n$. Counting the ternary strings of length $n$ satisfying the conditions, we consider two cases.

1) the last number is a zero. Since we cannot have consecutive zeroes, the $n-1$th number must be either 1 or 2. So we have $2b_{n-2}$ string ending in 10 or 20, since there are no troubles with consecutive zeroes when we add these numbers to a sequence of length $n-2$

2) The last number is either 1 or 2. Again, we can just take any ternary string of length $n-1$ which satisfy the conditions and add 1 or 2 at the end, since there are no zeroes which cause troubles. So there are $2b_{n-1}$ choices in this case.

It easily follows that $b_n=2b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}$.

My general advice for proving reccurence relations is to consider all possible cases very carefully and/or rephrasing the problem into smaller problems (divide-and-conquer). You should always try lots of small examples to see what's happening. Once one spots the pattern, it is often easier to generalize.